Error with npx nx migrate --run-migrations while upgrading from Angular 16 to Angular 19
I'm working on upgrading an Angular application from version 16 to 19 using Nx. I followed these steps:
Ran the command npx nx migrate@18.2.0 to prepare the workspace for Nx 18.
Installed the dependencies using npm install --force.
Ran npx nx migrate --run-migrations to apply the migrations.
However, I encountered the following error during the migrations:
> NX   Running migrations from 'migrations.json'

> NX   Failed to run 16.6.0-prefix-outputs from nx. This workspace is NOT up to date!

> NX   Unable to determine implementation path for "C:\Angular_Projects\repo-name\node_modules\nx\migrations.json:16.6.0-prefix-outputs"

   Pass --verbose to see the stacktrace.

Command failed: npx nx _migrate --run-migrations

 NX   Command failed: npx nx migrate --run-migrations


Steps I tried:

Checked migrations.json for any inconsistencies.
Ensured the correct version of Nx was installed.
Used the --verbose flag but didn’t get additional clarity on resolving the issue.
Deleted node_modules and reinstalled dependencies.
Cleared Nx cache using nx reset.

Environment:

Nx version: Initially migrated to 18.2.0
Node.js version: v20.13.1
npm version: 10.5.2
Angular version: 16 (upgrading to 19)

Question:
How can I resolve this issue and successfully run the migrations? Is there a workaround for this specific migration step (This workspace is NOT up to date!)? Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

You can't update to update Angular applications more than one major version at a time. I recommend you migrate to Angular 17, after to angular 18.
You can follow this official guide Update Guide

Thank you! I see the importance of upgrading one version at a time. However, since my issue is specific to Nx (npx nx migrate), how does the Angular update guide apply? Isn’t ng update used for Angular CLI rather than Nx migrations? Could you clarify?
